# Unable to reset partition groups (Window functions and PostgreSQL specifically)

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

I have a simple dataset like this:

```
SELECT UNNEST(ARRAY['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'B']) AS customer_name, generate_series(8, 1, -1) AS order_time;

+-------------+------------+
| customer_id | order_time |
+-------------+------------+
| "A"         | 8          |
+-------------+------------+
| "A"         | 7          |
+-------------+------------+
| "A"         | 6          |
+-------------+------------+
| "B"         | 5          |
+-------------+------------+
| "B"         | 4          |
+-------------+------------+
| "A"         | 3          |
+-------------+------------+
| "C"         | 2          |
+-------------+------------+
| "B"         | 1          |
+-------------+------------+
```

I am looking for one row:

```
+-------------+------------+
| customer_id | order_time |
+-------------+------------+
| "A"         | 6          |
+-------------+------------+
```

Which is to say, I want to get the first `order_time` of the latest (consecutive) `customer_id`. With the following SQL, I only ever obtain "3" as `order_time` from `customer_id` A. I can't seem to "reset" the partition.

```
SELECT customer_name, LAST_VALUE(order_time) OVER W
FROM
(
  SELECT UNNEST(ARRAY['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'B']) AS customer_name, generate_series(8, 1, -1) AS order_time
) X
WINDOW W AS (PARTITION BY customer_name ORDER BY order_time DESC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
ORDER BY order_time DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Using PostgreSQL 11.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use difference between

`ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY order_time DESC)` and

`ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY customer_name ORDER BY order_time DESC)` to provide grouping for `gaps-and-islands` structure :

```
SELECT XX.customer_name, LAST_VALUE(order_time) OVER W FROM
(
 SELECT X.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY order_time DESC)-
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY customer_name ORDER BY order_time DESC) 
             AS rn

   FROM
   (
     SELECT UNNEST(ARRAY['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'B']) AS customer_name, 
            generate_series(8, 1, -1) AS order_time
    ) X
 ) XX
WINDOW W AS (PARTITION BY rn ORDER BY order_time DESC 
ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
LIMIT 1;
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=1fc7bc5b8160d101188a20d9139fc35f)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks! Definitely seems to do the trick. I was hoping for something a little less complex / more built-in so to speak. But it seems I was on the right track with the alternate frame specification.

Comment: BTW quick question, I shouldn't need the "final" `ORDER BY` right? The one right before `LIMIT 1`.

Comment: Do we also really need to add `customer_name` to the `PARTITION BY rn`? Isn't that overkill?

Comment: yes @Jeff , good catch, we already figured in the previous step.